# Extracting values from XML string

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string variable (`getUserRoles`) containing the following:

```
<role name="olvers" guid="ee81e26aeb7cd" description="Used at" 
isdynamic="false">
  <extradata>
  </extradata>
  <include>
  <users>
     <user name="Q:www\sitename1" />
     <user name="Q:www\sitename2" />
     <user name="Q:"Q:www\sitename3" />
  </users>
  <groups />
 <smartobjects />
</include>
<exclude>
<users />
<groups />
<smartobjects />
</exclude>
</role>
```

I want to be able to extract the `name` attribute from each `user` element and store it in a list. In this case, I'd want the list to contain the following values:

- Q:www\sitename1
- Q:www\sitename2
- Q:www\sitename3

I have tried this:

```
XElement documentRoot = XElement.Load(getUserRoles);


XmlNodeList nodes = 
            root.SelectNodes("/role/extradata/include/users");
foreach (XmlElement node in nodes)
{
    log.Info("User in role : " + node.Value);
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. How can I extract these values and store them in a list?

Comment: because the OP probably wants only answers and can't execute a simple google search on their own @kjhughes, that's my best guess

Comment: "Unfortunately, this doesn't work" is never enough information. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ I'd note that your `extradata` element is empty though, so it's not clear why you've got it in your XPath expression...

Comment: You could use `root.Descendants("user")` instead of `SelectNodes`.

Comment: Thanks all for your contributions. For accepting question as answer, i can only do that when the answer has answered my question, i cannot be accepting any answer just for the sake of accepting answer thereby misleading others who will read my question.

Comment: @Methodman if i dont do google search i will posting questions on a daily basis, i only post questions when i have strict deadline to deliver and there is not enough time to do research, there are times i wont post any question for a period of six months while i am still working. At least someone eventually help out in a question that seemingly looks it has no answer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you XML has an error here:

**user name="Q:"Q:www\sitename3"**

Second, try this.

```
        var xmlstring =
            "<role name=\"olvers\" guid=\"ee81e26aeb7cd\" description=\"Used at\" isdynamic=\"false\">  <extradata>  </extradata>  <include>  <users>     <user name=\"Q:www\\sitename1\" />     <user name=\"Q:www\\sitename2\" />     <user name=\"Q:www\\sitename3\" />  </users>  <groups /> <smartobjects /></include><exclude><users /><groups /><smartobjects /></exclude></role>";

        var domdocument = new XmlDocument();
        domdocument.LoadXml(xmlstring);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (XmlElement selectNode in domdocument.SelectNodes("//users/user"))
        {
            sb.Append(selectNode.Attributes["name"].Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The path is wrong.  Should be `include/users/user` if you're reading from the root element.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

var doc = XDocument.Parse(getUserRoles);

var names = doc.XPathSelectElements("/role/include/users/user/@name")
               .Select(attribute => attribute.Value)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Having this error: The XPath expression evaluated to unexpected type System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute